# How to login Magento 2 from external web application

Tags: magento2, login

I have **laravel** application and **Magento2** application. When I login to laravel application it should also get login to Magento application.

Scenario:

1. User login to laravel application.
2. User click on buy now
3. Button in laravel application it redirects to magento2 application (with automatically login to magento).
4. User finished transaction and back to laravel application.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this module that allows an admin to login as a customer from the backend: 
**https://github.com/magefan/module-login-as-customer**

From there you can elaborate what you'll need in Laravel to be able to login the customer in Magento